# How to set session cookie only when need in flask

Tags: python, flask, cookies, session-cookies, flask-login

I would like to disable the session cookie in flask if the user isn't logged in to apply to GDPR. Is that possible? And how would you do so?

Comment: the why use cookies in the first place? Just don't use them at all and rely on the session storage.

Comment: But I think you need to store a session cookie to identify the user even if you use something like [flask-sessionstore](https://flask-sessionstore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)